# ionic2 contenteditable div not working in iOS devices

Tags: html, angular, ionic2

I'm using a content editable div element as an input filed for an ionic2 app.
It works perfectly on browsers and android devices but ios devices.

```
<div class="textarea" contenteditable="true" data-placeholder="Add emails"></div>

.ie-textarea {
    font-size:      fonts(ft-med) + .2;
    white-space:    normal;
    word-wrap:      break-word;
    min-height:     50px;
}

.ie-textarea:empty:before {
    content:    attr(data-placeholder);
    display:    block;
    color:      clr(grey-light);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this style in your css

```
.textarea,
[contenteditable] {
    -webkit-user-select: text;
    user-select: text;
}
```

Comment: Apparently, this is still needed up to iOS 15. On iOS 16 DIVs with the attribute `contenteditable` are editable without specifying `user-select` (or rather `-webkit-user-select`)